# Retrieve value from Database using cypress

Tags: cypress

Can anyone help me with the below scenario?

I have to execute a `select` statement and store the the result of the query in a variable using Cypress.

Below is the code I tried. I want to store the result of the query

`select id from invoices where INumber = '.invoiceNumber.'` to variable `rec`.

Please help me to achive this.

```js
cy.task('sqlServer:execute',"select id from invoices where INumber = '.invoiceNumber.'")
.then(function (recordset) {
    var rec = recordset
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is `sqlServer:execute`.

Comment: I am not sure this is the best use of what cypress should be used for. Are you testing the UX or the DB here? Is there a REST API that achieves the same thing? Just trying to understand what you are testing here.

Comment: sqlServer:execute - this one is to establish a connection to DB. I have to execute the select statement and store the result of the query. I really don't know how to achieve this. Above code is not correct, I tried that way but not giving any result.

Comment: Used the code to achive the SQL connection database = require('./database');
+const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');

Comment: Anyone tried to call sql server into typescript file?

Answer (score 6):

I can give you an example.
in test sepc.js

```
describe('test', () => {
  it("test", () => {
    cy.task("query", {
      sql: `
      select
        id
      from 
        invoice      
      `
    }).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.rows)
    });
```

in index.js

```
const pg = require("pg");
module.exports = ( on,config ) => {
  on( "task", {
      query ({ sql, values }) {
        const pool = new pg.Pool(config.db);
        try {
            return pool.query(sql, values)
        } catch (e) {
        }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: How would we achieve the same in typescript?