# Get data from database and use that in my cypress tests using type script

Tags: cypress

I have some scenarios to get data from database and use that in my tests using typescript

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried out. As a rule of thumb whenever you are asking a question on stackoverflow, please include the code that you have tried out.

Comment: I don't have any code, I need help on how we can achieve this in cypress using type script

Comment: You can refer to this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908980/retrieve-value-from-database-using-cypress